# Why do I get a "MySQLSyntaxErrorException:Access denied for user:" error?

Tags: java, mysql, spring, hibernate, jpa

when i run the application i have the errors mentioned in the stack trace.

> com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: Accès refusé pour l'utilisateur: ''@'@localhost'. Base 'db_hajar'

(I am using spring boot).
Can you help?

Here is the database class that I am using:

```
package demo.entities;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.Collection;

import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.JoinColumn;
import javax.persistence.OneToMany;

@Entity
public class Database implements Serializable {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)

    private int id_database;
    private String database_name;
    @OneToMany
    @JoinColumn(name="id_entity")
    private Collection<entities>entities;
    public int getId_database() {
        return id_database;
    }
    public void setId_database(int id_database) {
        this.id_database = id_database;
    }
    public String getDatabase_name() {
        return database_name;
    }
    public void setDatabase_name(String database_name) {
        this.database_name = database_name;
    }
    public Database() {
        super();
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }
    public Database(int id_database, String database_name) {
        super();
        this.id_database = id_database;
        this.database_name = database_name;
    }
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Database [id_database=" + id_database + ", database_name="
                + database_name + "]";
    }




}
```

Here is the entity's class:

```
package demo.entities;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.Collection;

import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.JoinColumn;
import javax.persistence.ManyToOne;
import javax.persistence.OneToMany;

@Entity
public class entities  implements Serializable {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)

    private int id_entity;
    private String entity_name;
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="id_database")
    private Database database;
    public int getId_entity() {
        return id_entity;
    }
    public void setId_entity(int id_entity) {
        this.id_entity = id_entity;
    }
    public String getEntity_name() {
        return entity_name;
    }
    public void setEntity_name(String entity_name) {
        this.entity_name = entity_name;
    }
    public entities() {
        super();
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }
    public entities(int id_entity, String entity_name) {
        super();
        this.id_entity = id_entity;
        this.entity_name = entity_name;
    }
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "entities [id_entity=" + id_entity + ", entity_name="
                + entity_name + "]";
    }

}
```

Here are the application property settings:

```
# DataSourcesettings:

 spring.datasource.url= jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/db_hajar
 spring.datasource.username= root 
 spring.datasource.password= 
 spring.datasource.driverClassName= com.mysql.jdbc.Driver

# Specifythe DBMS #

 spring.jpa.database = MYSQL 

 # Show or not log for each sqlquery 

 spring.jpa.show-sql = true 

 # Hibernateddlauto (create, create-drop, update)
  spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto = update
  # Naming strategy 
  spring.jpa.hibernate.naming-strategy = org.hibernate.cfg.ImprovedNamingStrategy
  spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect = org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect
```

the stack trace :

```
    com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: AccÃ¨s refusÃ© pour l'utilisateur: ''@'@localhost'. Base 'db_hajar'
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:377)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.getInstance(Util.java:360)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:978)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3887)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3823)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:870)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.proceedHandshakeWithPluggableAuthentication(MysqlIO.java:1659)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.doHandshake(MysqlIO.java:1206)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.coreConnect(ConnectionImpl.java:2234)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.connectOneTryOnly(ConnectionImpl.java:2265)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.createNewIO(ConnectionImpl.java:2064)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.<init>(ConnectionImpl.java:790)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.JDBC4Connection.<init>(JDBC4Connection.java:44)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:377)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.getInstance(ConnectionImpl.java:395)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver.connect(NonRegisteringDriver.java:325)
        at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.PooledConnection.connectUsingDriver(PooledConnection.java:307)
        at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.PooledConnection.connect(PooledConnection.java:200)
        at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool.createConnection(ConnectionPool.java:699)
        at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool.borrowConnection(ConnectionPool.java:633)
        at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool.init(ConnectionPool.java:484)
        at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool.<init>(ConnectionPool.java:142)
        at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSourceProxy.pCreatePool(DataSourceProxy.java:115)
        at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSourceProxy.createPool(DataSourceProxy.java:102)
        at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSourceProxy.getConnection(DataSourceProxy.java:126)
        at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DatasourceConnectionProviderImpl.getConnection(DatasourceConnectionProviderImpl.java:139)
        at org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SuppliedConnectionProviderConnectionHelper.prepare(SuppliedConnectionProviderConnectionHelper.java:51)
        at org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaUpdate.execute(SchemaUpdate.java:219)
        at org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaUpdate.execute(SchemaUpdate.java:203)
        at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.<init>(SessionFactoryImpl.java:522)
        at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1859)
        at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl$4.perform(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:852)
        at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl$4.perform(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:845)
        at org.hibernate.boot.registry.classloading.internal.ClassLoaderServiceImpl.withTccl(ClassLoaderServiceImpl.java:398)
        at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:844)
        at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.java:60)
        at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.createNativeEntityManagerFactory(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:343)
        at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:318)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1633)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1570)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:539)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:476)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:303)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:299)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:956)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:747)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:480)
        at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:118)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:686)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:320)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:957)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:946)
        at demo.DemoJpaApplication.main(DemoJpaApplication.java:10)
```

Comment: I have never used MySql, but it appears to be an error with MySql instructions.

Comment: Can you translate the error?

Comment: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: AccÃ¨s refusÃ© pour l'utilisateur: ''@'@localhost'. Base 'db_hajar'

Comment: @Chaitanya Access denied for user.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You question is sort-a-related to mySQL.  You just need to get past the Java error stack trace.  However, since I only recently had some experience with Java I have learned how to read some of the stack trace errors.  Read from the bottom up, where the top lines are the real answer.

Based on that nugget:

The top message: "com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: AccÃ¨s refusÃ© pour l'utilisateur: ''@'@localhost'. Base 'db_hajar'"...

Translate the french: "Refused for the user".  You pretty much get the answer: The database or table called "db_hajar" does not have the search or query permission.  I pretty sure it is NOT your code that is the problem, but the database or table permissions in mySQL.

You will need to get into mySQL as root, and GRANT access to a specific user.
See:  https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/privilege-system.html

On the side: I hope this machine does not have internet access or has a firewall in place (blocking port 3306), as you have mySQL running with root level credentials and no password in your code.  Yikes!  I would recommend that you set a root password (do not use it for queries), create a user and password, and give it pretty much full access to the database or table in question and supply those credentials in your Java program.  Once you get things working, avoid putting static credentials in your code, instead learn how to work with Java using certificates or a credential management system that securely holds credentials and can be retrieved when needing to authenticate.

Hope this helps!

Comment: it resolved the problem ,but now i don't have any error and i still can't generate the tables of the database db_hajar

Comment: Looking at your code, I do not see any code that refers to creating a table or any type of table schema information.  I would highly recommend referring to the JDBC documentation for supplying code that where you can describe a table and create it.   Keep in mind, you only need to do this once, so make sure you check for the table existence first, or drop and then recreate a table and then insert data.

Comment: I am using spring boot and i have seen that code in the official documentation ,all the informations are specified in application.properties

Comment: I am not familiar with "spring boot", however, your code still have jdbc calls (ie: spring.datasource.driverClassName= com.mysql.jdbc.Driver).  Unless there are predefined classes and structures setup to create a table when you make specific calls, you will need to add those instructions to your code.   You will need to add calls to open a connection, perform a query (SELECT, INSERT, DELETE, etc..) and then close the connection.  I do not see any SQL queries in your code.   There is something missing or my lack of how spring boot works.  :-(